# Need Columns to use picklist values as headers and show flitered (picklist value) in each column

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Haha, deleted the question. 
I have a picklist field called Account_Management_Type__c and it has the values of "Key (WIG)", etc. I am trying to set up the vf page so that each picklist value is a column of its own and each account (Overall_status__c) shows up in the column under the right header. similar to the picture.

Let me know it you need more details.

7/10/13 - updated code again (making progress!) The problem now is all I get is the URL for the formula field for Overall_Status__c - http://mastercontrolsandbox.mcsandbox1.cs15.force.com/example I tried a lot of options to fix this up I could not get it to work.. also, How can I get the columns to not have spaces? I want it all to line up at the top. I tried using order by, which worked sort of - it just grouped all of the spaces together.

[image]

```
public class ColumnControllerExt{
    Account a;
     public Account[] getaccsBucketedByType() {
        Account[] a = ([Select Id,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account]);
        return a;

    }

List<String> accNamesLst= new List<String>{ 'Key (WIG)' , 'Active Project', 'Active Opportunity > $50K', 'Partner-Managed', 'TAM-Managed', 'TSE-Managedd', 'Inactive'}; 
    Map<String, Account[]> accsBucketedByType = new Map<String, Account[]>();{ 
        for(String nameStr : accNamesLst) accsBucketedByType.put(nameStr, new List<Account>()); {
    for(Account acc : [Select Id,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c in:accNamesLst]) 
                                                             accsBucketedByType.get(acc.Account_Management_Type__c).add(acc);


        }   
    }   
}


<apex:page Controller="ColumnControllerExt">
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
#rowInfo,#rows{
        padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#rowInfo { 
    width:50px;
    display:none; 
}
 </style>

</head>
<body>

<table> 
                          <tr>
                            <th width="15">Key (WIG)</th>
                            <th width="15">Active Project</th>
                            <th width="15">Active Opportunity > $50K</th>
                            <th width="15">Partner-Managed</th>
                            <th width="15">TAM-Managed</th>
                            <th width="15">TSE-Managed</th>
                            <th width="15">Inactive</th>
                        </tr>

    <apex:repeat value="{!accsBucketedByType}" var="keya">
        <apex:repeat value="{!keya}" var="accRec">
            <tr>
                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='Key (WIG)'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='Active Project'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='Active Opportunity > $50K'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='Partner-Managed'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='TAM-Managed'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='TSE-Managed'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>

                 <td width="15" >
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!accRec.Account_Management_Type__c=='Inactive'}">{!accRec.Overall_Status__c}</apex:outputText>
                 </td>
             </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i dont think anybody here would be writing assignments for you. Folks here are more than willing to help even with some piece of code if there is some effort from your end. I am sure you have tried a few things to achieve what you want to do. pls post that over, i am sure there will be a lot of people to help you. No, i didnt downvote you :). But you are most likely to be downvoted if you ask people to write code for you

Comment: I wasn't asking to write the code, really. I just wanted to know how to start it.. Thanks, tho. I will post over some of what I have tried this weekend. Happy 4th! And for those of you that down-voted me, blah - sorry it came off the way it did.I was completely frustrated at the point I posted this. I will be more careful in my wording. :) Last thing I want to do is present this as my project if someone else wrote it. I had someone tell me I could use keys - I am just not sure how. Also, I was told that if I used a lookup instead of picklist it would be easier - not sure there either.

Comment: It would be good if you rephrased the question. I am not sure if understood your question. What are the headers you have on the screenshot and what are those dots.

Comment: Sorry - here is an example of what it looks like now , I need it to look like the above example. The idea is that you would click on a "status" icon to drill down to the account level.   http://mastercontrolsandbox.mcsandbox1.cs15.force.com/anyCustomerEmployeeTime

Comment: OK, I updated my code with what I have tried - the controller saves fine, but I am sure I am missing something. As for the vf page I get the error "**Unknown Property 'AccountStandardController.accsBucketedByType'** I did get it to save once, but got this error - **System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject 
Class.ColumnControllerExt.<init>: line 7, column 1**

Comment: Can you update the question on what needs to be done, it has a code and a picture. It is very hard to help out with minimum details. please update the requirement and I will try to help you complete the code :)

Comment: @rao Sorry - I updated the question! I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your contorller can be modified better but I took the same and did something close to what you want.

controller: ( almost the same)

```
public class ColumnControllerExt{
    private final Account accounts;
    Public MAP<String,LIST<Account>> accsBucketedByType{get;set;} 
    public List<string> list_of_accountmanagement{get;set;}
    public ColumnControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    list_of_accountmanagement = new List<string>{'Key (WIG)','Active Project','Active Opportunity > $50K','Partner-Managed','TAM-Managed','TSE-Managed','Inactive'};
    accsBucketedByType = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
    }
    public map<string,List<account>> getmap_values(){
        accsBucketedByType .put('Key (WIG)' ,[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c =: 'Key (WIG)']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('Active Project' , [Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c =: 'Active Project']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('Active Opportunity > $50K' ,[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where  Account_Management_Type__c =: 'Active Opportunity > $50K']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('Partner-Managed',[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where  Account_Management_Type__c =: 'Partner-Managed']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('TAM-Managed' ,[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where  Account_Management_Type__c =: 'TAM-Managed']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('TSE-Managed',[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where  Account_Management_Type__c =: 'TSE-Managed']);
        accsBucketedByType .put('Inactive',[Select Id,name,Overall_Status__c,Account_Management_Type__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c =: 'Inactive']);

    return accsBucketedByType;
    }

}
```

Page: this is where I have mashed up a little bit HTML and visualforce.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="ColumnControllerExt">
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
#rowInfo,#rows{
        padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#rowInfo { 
    width:50px;
    display:bold; 
}
 </style>

</head>
<body>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Customer Accounts">
  <table>

      <tr>
          <apex:repeat value="{!list_of_accountmanagement}" var="col_head">
              <th id="rows">{!col_head}</th>
          </apex:repeat></tr>
      <tr>

          <apex:repeat value="{!list_of_accountmanagement}" var="col_head">
              <td id="rowInfo" border="1">     
                  <apex:repeat value="{!map_values[col_head]}" var="col_val"> 
                   <apex:pageblockSection >

                      <apex:outputtext value="{!col_val.overall_status__c}" /> <br/>
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!col_val.Id}" style="color:red"/>              

                   </apex:pageblockSection>
                   <hr/>
                  </apex:repeat>
              </td>
          </apex:repeat>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </apex:pageBlock>

    </body>
</apex:page>
```

final Output:

[image]

Comment: This is outstanding - but is it possible to remove the string "Overall Status" from the final output?

Comment: just kick off  <apex:outputtext value="{!col_val.overall_status__c}" /> <br/> and replace with  {!col_val.overall_status__c}<br/> that should give just the status and not the text associated with the field